# Batch script - files to folders - with addition

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, directory

I'm working in a company that has far too many (millions) of record forms that all need organising.

Each file uses the following naming structure:

`xxxxx-xx-xx-xxxxx` e.g. `43144-02-40-21324.<ext>`

I've used in the past a batch script that puts files into a folder of the same name, but I'm looking for something slightly different.

I'd eventually like to end up with the following folder structure:
`C:\[root directory]\43144\02\40\21324.PDF`

Is something like this possible?
My knowledge of batch scripts is non existant, does anyone have the ability to quickly throw this together?

Thanks in advance, David

Comment: i'm totally sure this is possible, but, if you have it as an option, knocking something up in a vbs, or even c# console app could make it easier. Also, it would give you more flexibilty in handling files that might not be named right, and also handling files that may have the same name.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. The files do all carry this naming structure and I'm scanning them while going along, so they're named correctly, but I do see your point. Problem is my knowledge of this sort of thing is non existant, so I couldn't get very far on my own, I've edited my OP to clarify what I need. Thanks! David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=."
SET "destdir=u:\temp"
FOR /f "tokens=1,2,3,*delims=-" %%a IN ('dir /b/a-d "%sourcedir%\*-*-*-*"') DO (
 MD "%destdir%\%%a\%%b\%%c" 2>NUL
 IF EXIST "%destdir%\%%a\%%b\%%c\%%d" (ECHO "%destdir%\%%a\%%b\%%c\%%d" already exists
 ) ELSE ( 
  MOVE "%sourcedir%\%%a-%%b-%%c-%%d" "%destdir%\%%a\%%b\%%c\%%d" >nul 
 )
)
GOTO :EOF
```

This should set you on the right track - just need to set your source and destination directories...

Comment: One additional query, what if i wanted to have the full file name when it had been moved, so the structure would be like C:\[root directory]\43144\02\40\43144-02-40-21324.PDF I've had a look at the code, but can't figure it out. Thanks! - David

Comment: Two different ways. You could remove the `%%d` in the destination of the `move` statement which would mean the destination would end with `\` (if you ignore the rabbit's ears) and hence be a DIRECTORY - since the FILEname isn't specified, the source FILEname would be used. OR you could replace that `%%d` with `%%a-%%b-%%c-%%d` - same as the way the source filename was constructed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this isn't very hard to do:

1. We need to loop over all the files

   ```
   for %%F in (*.ext) ...
   ```

   For simplicity reasons we look in the current folder, so set it appropriately beforehand. But you can also supply a folder to look in.
2. For every file found, just call a subroutine that does the work

   ```
   ... do call :process "%%~F"
   ```
3. Exit the main method

   ```
   goto :eof
   ```
4. We need a subroutine now

   ```
   rem :process <filename>
   :process
   ```
5. Dissect the file name into its parts. Since those are all fixed-length we can just use substrings here.

   ```
   set "Filename=%~1"
   set "Part1=%Filename:~0,5%"
   set "Part2=%Filename:~6,2%"
   set "Part3=%Filename:~9,2%"
   set "Rest=%Filename:~12%"
   ```
6. Now we should probably check whether the folder we need to copy this into already exists or not

   ```
   if not exist C:\root\%Part1%\%Part2%\%Part3%\NUL mkdir C:\root\%Part1%\%Part2%\%Part3%
   ```

   This will create every folder along the way if necessary. Very handy.
7. Rename and move the file now

   ```
   move %1 C:\root\%Part1%\%Part2%\%Part3%\%Rest%
   ```
8. Exit the subroutine

   ```
   goto :eof
   ```

This should be it, more or less (bugs in my implementation notwithstanding). So here again in full:

```
for %%F in (*.ext) do call :process "%%~F"
goto :eof

rem :process <filename>
:process
    set "Filename=%~1"
    set "Part1=%Filename:~0,5%"
    set "Part2=%Filename:~6,2%"
    set "Part3=%Filename:~9,2%"
    set "Rest=%Filename:~12%"
    if not exist C:\root\%Part1%\%Part2%\%Part3%\NUL mkdir C:\root\%Part1%\%Part2%\%Part3%
    move %1 C:\root\%Part1%\%Part2%\%Part3%\%Rest%
goto :eof
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to iterate through files and for each file split name using `FOR`.
Then, you must ensure directories are created and copy/move your file to new path.

```
For %%f In (*.*) Do For /F "Tokens=1,2,3,4,5,6 Delims=-" %%i In ("%%f") Do Call :PutInPath %%f %%i %%j %%k %%k %%l
GoTo :EOF

:PutInPath
MD "C:\your dir\%2"
MD "C:\your dir\%2\%3"
MD "C:\your dir\%2\%3\%4"
REM You can use COPY, MOVE, REN, ...
COPY %1 "C:\your dir\%2\%3\%4\%5"
GoTo :EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Echo off
SET extension=%1

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for  %%f in ("*.%extension%") do (

SET substr=%%f
echo !substr!
copy !substr! !substr:~0,5!\!substr:~6,2!\!substr:~9,2!\!substr:~12,5!.%extension%
del !substr!
)
```

if the file format are fixed, we can do it like this!